# args4j : What argument threw the CommandLineException during the parsing?

Tags: java

I am using args4j to parse the arguments given to my program.

Here is the code where I define 2 arguments of Date type. The handler just parses the given date and throws a CommandLineException if the date is malformed.

```
@Option(name="-b", metaVar="<beginDate>", handler=DateOptionHandler.class, usage="...")
private Date beginDate;

@Option(name="-e", metaVar="<endDate>", handler=DateOptionHandler.class, usage="...")
private Date endDate;
```

I need to be able to return a different code (int value) if it is beginDate or endDate which throws an exception.

Currently, my main method looks like this :

```
CmdLineParser parser = new CmdLineParser(this);
parser.setUsageWidth(120);

try {
    parser.parseArgument(args);
} catch (CmdLineException e) {
    /* Print usage if an error occurs during the parsing */
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    System.err.println("Usage : java LaunchProgram [options]");
    e.getParser().printUsage(System.err);

    /* What I need to do : */
    if(optionWhichThrewTheException.equals("-b") return 2;
    if(optionWhichThrewTheException.equals("-e") return 3;

    /* Other arguments */
    return -1;
}
```

But I can't figure out how I can know which argument threw the exception (I looked the CmdLineException methods, but I found nothing).

Is there a way to obtain the parameter which can not be parsed ?

Thanks by advance for your help.

Comment: Won't you be able to tell it by checking if startDate == null or endDate == null?

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Unfortunatly, the beginDate and endDate are optional, so if beginDate is omitted and endDate throws an exception, it will return the wrong error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used args4j, but looking at its documentation, it seems that the exception is thrown by the option handler. So, use a BDateOptionHandler and a EDateOptionHandler, that throw a custom subclass of CmdLineException containing the needed information:

```
public class BDateOptionHandler extends DateOptionHandler {
    @Override
    public int parseArguments(Parameters params) throws CmdLineException {
        try {
            super.parseArguments(params);
        }
        catch (CmdLineException e) {
            throw new ErrorCodeCmdLineException(2);
        }
    }
}

public class EDateOptionHandler extends DateOptionHandler {
    @Override
    public int parseArguments(Parameters params) throws CmdLineException {
        try {
            super.parseArguments(params);
        }
        catch (CmdLineException e) {
            throw new ErrorCodeCmdLineException(3);
        }
    }
}

...
try {
    parser.parseArgument(args);
} 
catch (CmdLineException e) {
    ...
    if (e instanceof ErrorCodeCmdLineException) {
        return ((ErrorCodeCmdLineException) e).getErrorCode();
    }
}
```